# S3 invoke AWS Lambda issues with processing data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a general setup question for my AWS Lambda function that is invoked from an S3 upload.

For example my S3 bucket will have an `example.csv` that I want my function to run. Each row of `example.csv` I want the same lambda function to run at the same time. I do not know how to do this properly, for example having the function run with threading or multiprocessing (the function is written in python). I added `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to execute the function but it works horribly, some of the rows in S3 get skipped.

There is most likely some way I can do this without adding anything to the function, wanted to hear some ideas on how I could get around this.

Comment: If you don't actually need to do this in parallel then don't. If you do, then it should be simple enough for your Lambda function to read the entire CSV into memory, and then divide the processing of the rows among a number of threads.

Comment: Hey, if you want 1 lambda processing 1 row of your CSV, you can have a lambda calling other lambda several times (thus, creating instances of the other lambda)

Comment: if you can post some code here about what you want to do in that function that requires invoking again and again for each new row.
Also if you use pandas you can use `apply` function to invoke that function for each row. Might workout better for you